# sizeof structs and nested structs

Tags: c

I have set up structs in this way. 
When I print the sizeof(DATA), I get 16. Why is it 16? I thought it would be 8 as 4 for idx, and 4 for the ptr.

I allocate memory for the STUDENT struct and STATS struct array of size 50. Have I allocated enough memory?

```
typedef struct {
    int idNum;
    int classNum;

} STATS;
typedef struct {
    STATS * stats;
    int currGrade;

}STUDENT;

typedef struct {
    STUDENT * ptr;
    int idx;

} DATA;

//student_main.c
void function1()
{
    DATA d;
    func(&d);
}
//student.c
void func(DATA * d)
{
    Student * s = malloc(sizeof(STUDENT));
    d->ptr = s;
    d->ptr->currGrade = 1;

    STATS * arr = malloc(sizeof(STATS)* 50);
    d->ptr->stats = arr;
    d->ptr->stats[0].idNum = 1;
    d->ptr->stats[0].classNum = 1;
}
```

Comment: what is your architecture, and what architecture are you complying for?  on a 64-bit system pointers will be eight bytes, as will integers.  on a 32-bit system pointers and integers will be four bytes

Comment: "Why is it 16? I thought it would be 8 as 4 for idx, and 4 for the ptr."  Would not the next step be `printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof (STATS *), sizeof (int));` to validate that assumption.?  What was your result when trying this?

Comment: `Student` is used in function `func(...)` but not defined in this code.

Answer (score 3):

> I have set up structs in this way. When I print the sizeof(DATA), I
>   get 16. Why is it 16? I thought it would be 8 as 4 for idx, and 4 for
>   the ptr.

Because compiler (*may*) add padding between/behind struct elements to satisfy alignment constraints. You can read something about [data structure alignment here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

In your case of `DATA`, its 16B because (if your machine is x64)

```
typedef struct
{
    STUDENT * ptr;    // 8B pointer
    int idx;          // 4B int
                      // 4B padding
} DATA;
```

---

> I allocate memory for the STUDENT struct and STATS struct array of
>   size 50. Have I allocated enough memory?

It depends on your needs. You have allocated enough space for 50 structures. Remember to always use `sizeof(type)` while allocating dynamical memory.

Comment: I see. Since I also allocate memory for the STUDENT struct, I can assign member variables safely right? Like, d->ptr->currGrade = 1.

Comment: Yes you are doing it right. STATS to maximum index 49 `d->ptr->stats[49].idNum = 1;`, accessing further (index 50 and more) would lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: "Because compiler (may) add padding between `struct` elements to satisfy alignment constraints"-- unnamed padding may also be added at the end of a `struct`, as implied by your commented version of OP's `struct`, but not mentioned in the text of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will *pad* structures, for example to allow faster access to subsequent elements in 64 bit architectures.

You shouldn't ever need to worry about the numeric value of the size of a `struct`, as the compiler handles it. Use it only for comparisons, and ignore the absolute value (unless your hobby is reverse engineering the compiler)

Answer (score 0):

It can be 16 for one of two reasons - either You have 32 bit machine and the compiler adds some "space" in Your structure to make the operations faster. You can stop this behavior if You want your structures to be of the exact size, by adding `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` to the struct definition. Or You have 64 bit machine with 64 bit pointers and integers. Or a mix of both.

You have allocated enough memory. Doing `malloc(x * sizeof(struct xxx))` gives You the confidence.

I recommend reading this excellent article: [The Lost Art of C Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)